# Teams bot sso with identity provider

Tags: botframework, single-sign-on

In the instructions for adding authentication to a teams bot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication) they indicate the usage of an "Identity Provider", an app registration separate from the bot.

In the instructions for bot SSO (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots), there is no mention of this "Identity Provider" app registration.

In my testing, I am able to get the normal authentication working with the identity provider.  I am also able to get the SSO authentication working without the identity provider.

Is it possible to get the bot SSO working with an identity provider app registration?  I have tried several approaches, but none seem to work.

thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

are you maybe refering  to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-oauth?tabs=v1x

Comment: This document seems to refer to the usage of an external identity provider.  The bot SSO flow is similar in many ways, but requires specific steps such as exposing an api via an 'api://' url.  There seems to be no mention of single sign on in these instructions, and the fact that some of the screenshots there show login buttons implies that single sign on is not being used.